# How to drag a view from carousel

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am working on carousel concept for first time   please assist me to drag a view from carousel and to drop in a scroll view.  if possible please give me the brief code to drag the view from carousel.  i tried the Touches event methods but it is not working properly bcoz pan gesture is a default usage.   please assist me.
Thank you....

Comment: You could make a carousel of buttons and then set the buttons frame origin to the touch coordinates.

Comment: are you using a framework of sorts for the carousel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might probably find it useful to have a look at this [iCarousel class](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the already implemented drag n drop solution here:

https://github.com/firdousali86/SampleDragDropCarousel

it uses the same [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) class